# Android Values: Priorities for dimension values if not explicit in bucket

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android-screen-support

My question is best asked with an example.  Let's say you have a 10" Android tablet in landscape.  You have not specified a specific value for it's bucket in values-sw720dp-land but YOU DO have values in BOTH values-sw720dp AND values-sw600dp-land which value would it use?

Answer (score 1):

Original (incorrect): I just did an experiment to find out.  It would use values-sw600dp-land.  I think that probably makes some sense but I would have put my money on the alternative before my experiment.

Edit: No, the above is wrong.  It uses values-sw720dp as I originally thought.  I had three dimens files open in Eclipse and got confused as to which one I was looking at! :-P